# Cross sections of cusps in complex hyperbolic orbifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Suppose $H^n$ is the complex space form of bisectional curvature $-1$, $\Gamma$ is a discrete
subgroup of $PU(n, 1)$, the holomorphic isometry group of $H^n$. Let $M=H^n/\Gamma$, then
$M$ is a hyperbolic orbifold.  If $\Gamma$ is torsion free, we know that $M$ is a manifold.
Suppose further that $M$ has finite volume and is non-compact, then $M$ must have cusp ends.
What do we know about the cross sections of the cusp ends?   Can we say that each cross section is a smooth manifold, or the cross section itself maybe a singular orbifold? What
references can I see for this question? Thanks!

Comment: Does this paper by Hummel and Schroeder help?
http://www.springerlink.com/content/v74834r21r82637x/fulltext.pdf



Comment: This paper has some information on this question: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0409.5278
 

Comment: See papers by Kamishima: http://www.springerlink.com/content/71003531454282n0/ and http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603726

Comment: Thanks! These papers imply that it is restrictive to be a cross-section of a complex hyperbolic cusp.

Comment: The link in [Ian's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74074/cross-sections-of-cusps-in-complex-hyperbolic-orbifolds#comment188554_74074) is broken, here's a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409278